# Unix datetime to QDateTime

Tags: qt

I wanto to convert UNIX time to QDateTime like this

```
int unixTime = 1234567890;
QDateTime timestamp;
timestamp.setTime_t(unixTime);
qDebug() << timestamp.toString(Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate);
```

But I always get
  1/1/1970 5:00 AM

What's the problem in my code.

Comment: It returns `2/14/2009 12:31:30 AM` for me.

Comment: It returns "2/13/09 11:31 PM" for me. I think that timezone affects return value somehow.

Comment: I have also read in documentation that timezone effects, but don't the solution. My time is UTC+5

Comment: it should work, only explanation why it doesn't is that your cache is corrupted, so `make clean` (clean project) then `make` (build it again).